# Find index of a minimum property in a part of the collection

Tags: c#, collections, minimum

I have a class Bar:

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Open { get; set; }
    public double High { get; set; }
    public double Low { get; set; }
    public double Close { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
}
```

and a collection

```
minDataCollection<Bar>
```

I am trying to find an index of a bar with lowest bar.Low within a "width" of bars starting n-bars back from the current bar.
The problem is if I create another collection of size "width" and find the minimum I will loose connection to indexes of main collection.

Comment: Is 'minDataCollection' a class you wrote?

Comment: minDataCollection<Bar> is an Observable Collection

Comment: What's wrong in adding the index of the start element to the index of the sublist item you find?

Comment: If I find Min value using List.Min(); I will learn only min value. Now how can I get the index? I didn't find any simple method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ's `Select`-with-an-index, then [`MinBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var index = collection.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
                      .MinBy(pair => pair.value.Low).index;
```

Comment: I am new to programming (though I studied 4 thick books), so I can be wrong. It seems to me that this code will look through the entire minDataCollection<Bar> for the index of value with the lowest "Low" property. I need to analyze only several bars that are n-bars away (towards the beginning of the collection) from the current bar. I know the index of current bar - iCurrBar.

Comment: @Vitaly: Ah, sorry - that wasn't terribly obvious. Will edit later - I don't have time right now.